# looking for a one-file filesystem or archiving file format

Tags: c, filesystems, zip, file-format, archiving

I'm looking for some filesystem, or archiving file format, with transparent compressing/decompressing support, and can be opened in windows (as a file) by some tool(like winrar or 7-zip), and have some easy to use c interfaces

As far as I've found, zip fileformat is the closest, transparent decompressing, simple c interface (Minizip), but zip format is not suited for file lookup by filename. the UDF filesystem (in iso format) may be bettar at filename lookup (it's a guess, I haven't look very deep), but I haven't found a c interface

Yet I think there must be a more obvious and simpler approach than zip and iso, so, is there?

**UPDATE**

I have failed to find such a filesystem, especially transparent decompressing. yet there are good ones, like [whefs](http://code.google.com/p/whefs/), but without transparent decompressing. and none filesystem approaches, namely DBM(CDB, gdbm, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need *archiving* (i.e. sequential compressing and decompression, with no modifications), then ZIP is a standard and probably there's nothing close to ZIP in popularity. However ZIP is not effective when you manipulate files in it (i.e. when you need a virtual file system). In the latter case you can use CodeBase File System, Solid File System (our product) or one of similar products.

Comment: Thanks, your advice would be truly, Solid File System looks tempting. but I'm looking into the opensource world, so... I'm looking after DBM based approaches now

Comment: @tdihp we offer free licenses in some cases (if you have a public free project).

Answer (score 4):

Zip is the *de facto* standard solution for compression and archiving. Judging by the following diagram of the format ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29)), lookup by name occurs in the "central directory" and should not involve a scan through the entire file.

[image]

Comment: thanks. this lookup is really good for listing files inside, but I really want a indexing structure that can find a file entry by name very fast, not look through the whole entral directory

Answer (score 3):

[zziplib](http://zziplib.sourceforge.net/) (and probably others) allows you to read the directory inside a zip file like it were a normal filesystem directory.

Comment: Thanks. but I think zziplib uses zip format, and the zip format is not that "specialized" at intense file query.